# Remap ESC to Option-ESC in Office (Excel, Word, etc) with karabiner-elements

Tags: window-manager, karabiner

When I am using Safari in full screen, and I press ESC key it's minimized. So that's why I started using [karabiner-elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

I install it, I use the first option in [this page](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=esc) and the problem **is solved**.

Now, I want to know if in **Office** (Excel, Word, PorwerPoint) **I can use the same settings**.

In the page I mentioned before I didn't find the option I want.

In the video that I attach, the screen is **minimized when I press ESC**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to have <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> function like that of remapped Safari's <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

In Karabiner Elements, you have to *modify* the JSON  file and *remove* the entry making it for Safari only:

You have to **remove** the following section:

```
{
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com.apple.Safari"
              ]
            }
```

Karabiner-Elements has a number of [examples](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/) that you can base new keys from.  It's also important that your read the [manual](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/) on how the application functions.

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac Ventura 13.4.1. I did it as described and Power point still exit Full Screen when ESC is pressed.